# align text equally

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

this question may be asked earlier, but I really dont know how to search it also.

What I want to achieve is something like this.

```
city     : some city
state    : some state
pincode  : some pin code
phone no : some phone number
```

the city   : is one text view and some city is the second text view. both in linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                              android:orientation="horizontal"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="City : "
                          android:textSize="15sp"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />
                <TextView android:text="Some city"
                          android:textSize="15sp"
                          android:id="@+id/lblPermanentCity"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
```

any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pull this off with just two TextViews. The problem is that the title ("city") is left aligned and the colon is right aligned.

If you can live with left aligned colons, you can use the `layout_weight` property to make the title column the same size on all lines, like so:

```
...
<TextView android:text="City:"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="0"
          android:layout_weight="40"/>
<TextView android:text="some city"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="0"
          android:layout_weight="60"/>
```

This will give the title column 40% of the width and the values column 60% of the width. Make sure your `LinearView`'s `layout_width` is `match_parent`

If you really must have the colons in the middle, just add a third TextView for the colon, giving it a fixed width (`wrap_content` with the same content is enough)

Comment: do i need to change the width property to match_parent of all the parent linearLayouts?

Comment: My bad i had accidently change height property

Comment: can u please tell me why layout_width must be mentioned as 0 ?

Comment: Because Android sucks... layout_width must be specified. If you don't set it to 0, Android is going to use it and ignore the layout_weight parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use three `TextView`s per row, one for city, state, etc, one for the ":" and one for the "some city", etc. Then place them in a `RelativeLayout` and align your colons(:) to the right edge of the largest `TextView`(probably your "phone no").

Comment: Yes I can do this. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you table layout.I thinks it's best solution to your problem.